# CSS responsive footer - hide and show another

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS Footer and the main div is `#footer`.

I then have another div called `#small-footer` which has `display:none;` in the css.

I have another style sheet called `responsive.css` which has my media queries in it.

In `responsive.css` i have the following:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #footer {
        display:none;
    }
    #footer-inner {
        display:none;
    }
    #footer-top {
        display:none;
    }
    #footer-left {
        display:none;
    }
    #footer-middle {
        display:none;
    }
    #footer-right {
        display:none;
    }
    #footer-bottom {
        display:none;
    }
    #small-footer {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

so it hides all the footer code when the screen size gets smaller but for some reason the #small-footer div is not appearing.

any ideas what this could be?

I have created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Er7vy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put your `#small-footer` within your `#footer` so as the footer is display none, everything inside it will be hidden (including your small footer)

http://jsfiddle.net/Er7vy/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
footer-inner {
    display:none;
}
```

That means that anything in that div will not appear, and the #small-footer div  is in that div.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `min-width` to show your large footer, and hide the small. That makes the small footer visible for all screen sizes until you reach the larger break point. And move `#small-footer` out of `#footer-inner`. That way `#footer` is always visible.

```
#small-footer { display:block }
#footer-inner { display:none; }

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    #footer-inner { display:block; }
    #small-footer { display:none; }
}

<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer-inner">...</div>
    <div id="small-footer">...</div>
</div>
```

This approach also saves you all the redundant `display:none`s that you're currently using. Less code is best code :-\